# Get content inside a td tag when hovered over

Tags: jquery

```
<td>
   Some stuff here
   <span style="display: none;">sekret stuff here</span>
</td>
```

How would I go about getting the content of the `<span>` tag in that td, so that my output would be "sekret stuff here", using jQuery?

I've tried a couple of different things, but couldn't get anything to work. =/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will alert the contents of the `span` when hovering over the `td`, only if the `td` has an `span` element inside:

```
$('td').mouseover(function() {
    if($(this).find('span').size() > 0) {
        // This will alert 'sekret stuff here'
        alert($(this).find('span').html());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's just one of these on a page:

```
$('td span').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using pure CSS, because it is potentially faster.

HTML:

```
<td>
   <a class="magic_link" href="#">Some stuff here
   <span>sekret stuff here</span></a>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
a.magic_link:link,
a.magic_link:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

a.magic_link:link span,
a.magic_link:visited span {
    display: none;
}

a.magic_link:hover span {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with the contents after its been hovered over the td cell you need to give the td cell an ID.

```
<td id="mycell">
    Some stuff here
    <span style="display:none">Sekret stuff</span>
</td>
```

And then use jQuery to bind a mouseover event and do something with the contents:

```
var cell = $('#mycell'), span = cell.find('span');

cell.bind('mouseover', function () {
    var contents = span.html();
    // do something with contents
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got other `td`'s on the page that **don't** contain a `span`, you'll probably want to use the [`:has`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has#selector) selector to make sure you're only binding to `td` that has a `span` child.

```
$('td:has(span)').mouseover(function(e) {
    var content = $(this).find('span').html(); //or .text() for the plain text
    //do something with the content
});
```

I think you're probably better off giving either the `td` or the `span` a semantic class though, it'll make the intent of your HTML a bit more obvious. Something like

```
<td>
   Some stuff here
   <span class="sekret" style="display: none;">sekret stuff here</span>
</td>
```

... and modify the selector in the javascript to be something like

```
$('td:has(.sekret)').mouseover(...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('td').hover(function() {
    var c = $(this).children('span');
    if (c.length > 0) {
        alert($(c[0]).text());
    }
});
```

It will bind an event to every `td` on your page, and look for child `span` elements, popping up an alert with the contents of the first `span` inside the `td`.  You can replace the `alert()` part of the code with whatever you'd like to do with the `span` contents.  Note that inside that code, `this` will refer to the `td` element.

Comment: `hover` requires two functions as parameters, mouseover and mouseout. Also, what's the point doing `$(c[0]).text()` as `c.text()` would work as well?

Comment: I guess if you had tried the code, you would see that it works fine.  The second parameter is not required.  As well, you would use `c[0]` here because `children()` returns an array of child elements, so if you wanted to access only the first one, that would obviously be `c[0]`.  `c` would be all the elements.  Thanks for the down vote anyway though.